# How to reload new update in Django project with Apache, mod_wsgi?

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am making a project using the Django framework. I have hosted a test server with Apache+mod_wsgi. When I change some lines of code, I upload the file and test it in a browser. But the new changes are not shown unless I reload/restart (`/etc/init.d/apache2 reload`).

Is there any other way to reload/refresh new changes besides reloading Apache?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, touch your `wsgi` configuration file.

For me, my server restart script is as simple as `touch /srv/grove_project/conf/apache/django.wsgi`.
Build it into your server management scripts and it's a nice graceful restart.

For more info and when this applies: https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode

From The Man himself: this only works with `mod_wsgi` in daemon mode.

Comment: It should though be noted that touching the WSGI script file only works to reload the whole application if you are using mod_wsgi daemon mode.