# How to clear code cache in python/django?

Tags: python, django

Sorry, I'm newbie on python.
I change code in .py file but no changes happens.
Guess, script code is cahced in memory.

What should I do to make my changes working?

PS: tried to delete complied .pyc file, no luck 8-(
guess, IO need to try to restart uwsgi/nginx?

Answer (score 2):

Older versions of django

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

New version of django has this:

```
python manage.py clean_pyc
```

If you simply want to restart the webserver it depends on the configuration you are using:

1. via gunicorn:
   use [`--reload`](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/19.0/settings.html#reload) option
2. via django inbuilt runserver: 
   [since version 1.7 it automatically does that.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port)

Answer (score 1):

Just touch the WSGI file: `touch wsgi.py` and your project should refresh.

Please have a look at this similar request: [How to reload new update in Django project with Apache, mod_wsgi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17058928/how-to-reload-new-update-in-django-project-with-apache-mod-wsgi)