# Django templates not updating

Tags: django, apache2

I'm running a small django website with wsgi and apache on an ubuntu server.

I made a minor change to one of my template files in my Django app, and the change is not showing up on my server. However, if I run python manage.py runserver, and curl -l 127.0.0.1:8000, I can see the change. I've tried restarting apache, with no luck.

My urls.py for the page is just 
url(r'^page/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="page.html")),

I've verified that the change is not present by checking on other devices and using incognito mode.

My wsgi.py contains

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "django_site.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And my /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf contains

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName www.site.com
    ServerAlias site.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@site.com

    Alias /static /opt/django_site/django_site/static
    <Directory /opt/django_site/django_site/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /opt/django_site/django_site/django_site>
            <Files wsgi.py>


    Alias /static /opt/django_site/django_site/static
    <Directory /opt/django_site/django_site/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /opt/django_site/django_site/django_site>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess django_site processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} python-path=/opt/django_site:/opt/django_site/django_site/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup django_site
    WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/django_site/django_site/django_site/wsgi.py


</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Are you using mod_wsgi? If yes, this will help you: [How to trigger source code reloading](https://code.google.com/archive/p/modwsgi/wikis/ReloadingSourceCode.wiki)

Comment: I am using mod_wsgi, but unless I'm misunderstanding the page you linked, mod_wsgi should update its source when you restart apache.

Comment: I think you're using mod_wsgi in embedded mode. See this: [Why are you using embedded mode of mod_wsgi?](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html)

Basically you need to change mod_wsgi to daemon mode, then "touch" your wsgi configuration file to reflect the changes. Take a look at this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17058928/how-to-reload-new-update-in-django-project-with-apache-mod-wsgi

Comment: I read the article, but I'm not sure how to tell which mode I'm in, or how to switch to daemon. I tried the script to check which mode, by replacing the content of my wsgi.py with it, and then restarted apache2 and tried accessing the site, but nothing was different. I've updated the original post with the contents of my apache conf file, and it looks the same as how the article says to enable daemon mode.

Comment: Perhaps it has to do with caching https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51747782/django-template-is-not-changed-after-update-possible-cache