# Django template is not changed after update (possible cache)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I have a problem with Django. Possibly with it's cache. Version 1.11

I use template in urlpatterns like :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^service_preview/', include(serviceprev_urls, namespace = 'service_preview')),
    url(r'^service_preview/',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='service_preview.html')),
]
```

After a lot of updates, applied to my template, the changes stop appearing in user's browser. I have actual template in my templates folder and some previous version when preview source code in browser. If I rename the template (this should raise error because template is absent), I still have that previous template in browser source. Browser page refreshing, clearing browser cache etc does not help. There are no duplicates of this page in my template folder.

When I use another template, all is ok.
Possibly, problem is in django cache. I don't know how to force clear cache, maybe it would be a solution.

I put this at app setting file, but it doesn't help.

```
CACHES = {'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',}}
```

EDIT:
i found i have duplicate html name, located in the same project, but other application's template directory. May it cause a problem

Comment: did you try ctrl+f5 in the browser to clean the cache to see if it works

Comment: tried, no effect (at other computers browsers show my old page). After wasted 2 hours today i found "solution" - i renamed template in project and in template's folder to force it work correctly.

Comment: yeah but that doesn't seem like a solution to me... but I hope it will work for you

Answer (score 7):

By default, the Django template loader [caches templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/api/#configuring-an-engine) when `DEBUG = False`. After changing a template, you need to restart the server (e.g. Apache or gunicorn) to see the changes. This behaviour is not affected by the `CACHES` setting.

Comment: debug was (and is) True, runserver command was restarted several times with no success in solving rtemplate problem

Comment: @Vova how where you able to solve this as I am currently encountering the same issue.

Comment: @Nnaobi see the edit in the original question. It looks like the problem was that two templates had the same name, and they were editing the template that Django wasn’t using. Giving the template a unique name solved the problem.

Comment: I found that I had a similarly named application...using the ```app_name:view_name``` in my templates helped solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Mind boggling. But resolved. Turns out, there was a second set of every folder and file. My structure was something like this:

- Project folder (Folder with manage.py)

  - Project Folder (Folder with settings.py)

    - Project Folder (Copy of original main project folder, so this had a copy of all contents including the project folder, app folder, all files and folders from the original project folder)
  - App Folder

    - All Expected files and folders (views, static, templates etc)

Since the duplicates were kind of deep in the structure, I wasn't going that far to check and even missed it on the IDE. I thought I was editing templates and other.py files from my App folder, but I was actually editing the same files (copies) from the duplicate App folder located inside the duplicate Project folder. I copied the files that I needed and placed them in the main App folder, deleted the duplicates, and every change is reflecting again! Very silly on my part in retrospect, but it is what it is.

PS. I know it's an old thread, but this appeared top of the list for me while searching for a solution. Hope it makes someone else's life a little easier!